# Using Javascript to Post Form Search Results to 1 of 2 Locations (iframe on separate page)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

I am trying to get 2 search forms to combine into 1 search form with radio buttons to determine where the search goes. The results will either post to the "Relevanssi" plugin for Wordpress results or to an iframe on another page in the Wordpress site.

I have worked with another programmer to get this far, but they are now stuck and I am lost. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the current code used that we have come up with and it works exactly how I want it to work except for 1 part.

Javascript:

```
<script>
function submitForm() {
if (document.searchForm.source.value == "website") {document.searchForm.action = "http://www.website.com/"
document.searchForm.target = "_self"
document.searchForm.s.value = document.searchForm.searchTerms.value
} else {
document.searchForm.action = "http://catalog.website.com/search"
document.searchForm.target = "catalog_search_iframe"
}

console.log('New action: ' + document.searchForm.action)
console.log('Values: ' + document.searchForm.s.value + ";" + document.searchForm.searchTerms.value)

document.searchForm.submit()
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<p>
<form name="searchForm" action="" method="post" target="">
<div class="form-field-label">
Search for: 
</div>              
<div class="form-field-field">
<input id="searchTerms" name="searchTerms" type="text" value="" /> 
<input id="s" name="s" type="hidden" value="" /> 
</div>
<div class="form-field-radio-inputs">
<input type="radio" name="source" value="website" checked="checked">Website<br>
<input type="radio" name="source" value="catalog">Catalog<br>
</div>
<div class="form-field-buttons">
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm();" name="buttonSearch" value='Search' />
</div>
</form>
<iframe style='width: 640px; height: 700px; border: 1px solid #000000;' name='catalog_search_iframe'></iframe> 
</p>
```

The above code will take the search term and place it in the "Relevanssi" plugin for Wordpress results page if the "Website" radio is selected, and it will put the Catalog search results in the iframe on the current page if the "Catalog" radio is selected. All of this works perfectly.

But I would like to place the iframe on another page of the Wordpress site.

Is there a way to set this up in the javascript code above to direct the "Catalog" search results to the iframe on another page in the site?

Comment: you have to pass the form data from the outer page into the iframe. there is no shortcut to post directly into an iframe *on another page*. if the iframe is on the same page you can change the target value to match the name of the iframe.

Comment: You would have to post your form to the base page that contains the other iframe (so you’d need that page to be able to accept a form post), and have that page in turn pass the form data to the iframe as it loads.  There is no direct automatic way to load the new base page and submit to the iframe it contains, using just javascript.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, my javascript target for the iframe would become the search results page that the iframe is on, and then on that page I would need to direct the information to the iframe itself. Is that correct?